# Can I restrict access to certain files for a certain process?

Tags: linux, permissions, chroot

Is it possible to start a process in Linux, and restrict its access to certain files/directories? For example:

```
$ start-process --enable-dir=./sandbox --exec="some-script.sh"
```

`some-script.sh` won't be able to do anything outside of `./sandbox`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`chroot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) to set the root directory of your process tree. This means however, that all dependencies of that process must be available in it's new root.

*There are a number of packages that can help you setup chroot-environments for your needs. Google is your friend ;)*

---

**Some pointers on building a chroot environment**

When builing a chroot for some program or daemon you have to have a complete environment for the program you want to *chroot*. This means you have to provide a minimum system in a directory. That might contain:

- A shell and some shell utilities, or a variant of busybox. (this encompasses the next step too, if you aren't planning on deploying one single static executable that is).
- Libc and other dependent shared libraries.

  - You need to check shared library dependencies using `ldd` or `objdump`. Every library that appears has to be in your *private* root directory. This step might be repeated several times for every executable and library you need. Note that some libraries, which are linked explicitly at runtime using `dlopen` need to be checked *separately*.
- Depending on what you plan to *chroot* a minimal `/dev` tree.

  - If you plan to chroot a daemon process this may well be needing some minimal files in `/dev` such as `random` or `zero`. You can create those with the `mknod` command. Please refer to the `mknod` [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mknod.html), as well as the linux documentation on which major/minor numbers which device should [have](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/device-list/devices.txt).
- Also depending on what you plan to *chroot* is a minimal `/etc`. Files needed therein are:

  - A minimal passwd and shadow (**not** your system passwd/shadow).
  - A minimal `mtab` containing `/`.
  - A minimal `group` (again, **not** your system group file).

You have to start somewhere, so it's best to start with the prerequisites for you program. Refer to your *documentation* for specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you want to `chroot` the process, so that it can only access a directory and its sub-directories, and only execute some defined commands.

See [How to chroot](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/current/doc/chroot-login-howto.html).